# Is my solution correct in terms of proof? I can't prove directly that $f(x)=4$.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, functional-equations

Given  $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ and the following conditions:

1. $f(x+2)\cdot f(x+3)=16$,
2. $f(x)+f(-x)=8$,

we have to find integral $\int_{-8}^8 f(x-2019)dx$. So, if we plug in $0$, then $f(0)+f(0)=8$. Therefore, $f(0)=4$. Then plug in $-2$ in first equation,  we get $f(0)\cdot f(1)=16$, therefore $f(1)=4$, analogically plug $x=-1$ and I think that $f(x)=4$, so answer will be  $64$ (value after integrating). Is this correct? How can i prove it in a better manner?

Comment: If $f$ was a polynomial, then $f \equiv 4$ would follow quite easily. If not, it can also be $f(x) = \sin(\pi x) + 4$, for example.

Comment: I can prove that for integers, f(x)=4, but I am trying to prove for real numbers

Comment: @mathboy Yes, but that does not seem right (at least I can't see yet). Look at the counterexample in my previous comment.

Comment: @mathboy Are you sure that $f$ is not said to be polynomial?

Comment: sin(2pi+pix)=sin(px), f(x+3)=sin(pi(x+3))=sin(pix+3pi)=-sin(pix), therefore, 
  -sin(pix)*sin(pix)=16 --> (sin(pix))^2=-16, therefore no real. idk is this correct ?

Comment: idk, nothing was mentioned about  that.

Comment: @mathboy Then, the question does not have a unique answer.

Comment: @mathboy Is $f$ atleast continuous ?

Comment: nothing mentioned, you are right, no unique answer I think as well now.

Comment: I feel it can still be shown

Comment: @Beta What do you mean?

Comment: The solution to the functional equation is not unique, but the value of the integral is determined by the conditions.

Comment: After all, the functional equation can be solved. Look at my second solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From 1 we have $f(x+1)f(x)=16$, so $\displaystyle f(x+2) = \frac{16}{f(x+1)} = \frac{16}{16/f(x)} = f(x)$. Since $f$ has period $2$ then
$$\int_{-8}^8 f(x-2019)\,dx = \int_{-8}^8 f(x-1)\,dx = 8 \int_0^2f(x-1)\,dx$$
$$ = 8 \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx = 8\int_{-1}^0f(x)\,dx+8\int_{0}^1 f(x)\,dx$$
$$=8 \int_{0}^1f(-x)\,dx + 8\int_{0}^1 f(x)\,dx = 8 \int_0^1f(x)+f(-x)\,dx = 8 \int_0^1 8\,dx = 64$$

Comment: Interestingly, this solution is the same if we change $16$ by any other positive real. My second solution prove the stronger fact that $f$ is constant. That solution doesn't work if we change the $16$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more direct solution:

From 1 we have $\displaystyle f(1+x)=\frac{16}{f(x)}$ and from 2 we have $f(x) = 8-f(-x)$.

Then $$f(x) = f(1+x-1) = \frac{16}{f(x-1)} = \frac{16}{8-f(1-x)} = \cfrac{16}{8-\cfrac{16}{f(-x)}} = \cfrac{16}{8-\cfrac{16}{8-f(x)}}$$

Solving for $f(x)$ we get $f(x)=4$.